# Where should I put CMakeLists.txt files?

Tags: c, build, cmake

We would like to develop a few dynamically-linked libraries in C, each for both Linux and Windows. We would like to use CMake.

How do we organize directories and where do we put those `CMakeLists.txt` files? (Or should we have just one?)

Answer (score 6):

There is no single way that it must be done, but here is one possible way:

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/
    CMakeLists.txt
    lib1/
        CMakeLists.txt
        lib1.c
    lib2/
        CMakeLists.txt
        lib2.c
    app/
        CMakeLists.txt
        app.c
include/
    lib1.h
    lib2.h
```

While you can do everything in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file, it will get large and messy very quickly if your project is complex.

Comment: Please and where to get those `build` directories? -- I assume each of the libraries should have one. Am I right?

Comment: I put the build directory at the same level as the src/ and include/ directories.  While in the build directory, run the command "cmake .." and then "make" (assuming on *nix).  This is called an out-of-source build, so none of your build artifacts get mixed up with your source files.  The build directory structure will match your project's directory structure, so for example, all your build files for lib1 will be in build/src/lib1.

Comment: @able that's still in-source because the build artefacts end up in the project directory. @cartesius00 a project designed with flexibility in mind should allow the user to choose any location for their build directory. That way, they can have multiple configurations built at once. See [this section of the CMake FAQ](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#out-of-source-build-trees) for details. You'll know if you're doing it right if you can `cd /tmp && cmake /home/cartesius00/my-project`.